# Add caption with figure number to image next to item list

Tags: floats, captions

I´m trying to add a caption under a image that is to the right of an item list. The caption appears but it doesn´t say figure x: Enter Caption Here. How do I do this?

This is the code I´m using:

```
\begin{minipage}[l]{0.45\textwidth}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
    \item Item 4
\end{itemize}

\end{minipage}

\hfill

\begin{minipage}[r]{0.45\textwidth}

\centering

\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{}

\caption{Enter Caption Here}

\end{minipage}
```

Comment: You can't use the `caption` command outside of a `figure` or `table` environment.

Comment: If you want the combination if image and list to float, just enclose both and the caption in a `figure` environment. If you don't want them to float, add the `caption` package to your preamble and use the `\captionof{figure}{enter caption here}` command instead.

Comment: In order to show list and image side-by-side, you will also have to comment out or remove the empty lines around the `\hfill` command.

Comment: You should get an error message such as: `\caption outside float.` As soon as you get an error message, do not look at the outpu. Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome here !

First things first, it's easier to help you if you provide a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). For the following, I suppose you're using `article` class.

There are some problems in your snippet code we have to tackle first :

- If you want `minipage` environment next to each other, you've to remove the line spaces around `\hfill`. With a blank line, LaTeX will insert a blank line.
- If you compile, the log file pointed to an error : `! LaTeX Error: \caption outside float.`. This message means that you cannot use `\caption{}` outside a float environment like `figure` or `table`. Therefore, you have to use either a figure environment or the package `caption` to use the command `\captionof{figure}{}`. This is the solution I proposed here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption} %%numbered caption outside floats

\begin{document}
 \begin{minipage}[l]{0.45\textwidth}
     \begin{itemize}
         \item Item 1
         \item Item 2
         \item Item 3
         \item Item 4
     \end{itemize}
 \end{minipage}
 \hfill          %%Remove blank lines here
 \begin{minipage}[r]{0.45\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}
     \captionof{figure}{Enter Caption Here}  %%\captionof{figure} instead of \caption{}
 \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: @Vincent Thank you for editing, i've encountered some troubles with code markers !

Comment: No problem ! :)

Answer (score 3):

Another solution to get the output you're looking for is to use the `wrapfigure` environment from the [`wrapfig`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) package.

Here's an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{Enter Caption Here}
\end{wrapfigure}

~ %Used here because a wrapfigure environment cannot be placed directly before a list environment.
\begin{itemize}
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
    \item Item 4
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would be carful when combining list-like environments with `wrapfig`since the `wrapfig` documentation explicitly states: "You must not specify a wrapfigure in any type of list environment or or immediately before or immediately after one. It is OK to follow a list if there is a blank line (\par) in between."

Comment: @leandriis Yes, it's indeed a good idea to be careful (in fact, I must say that I learned to be somewhat careful whenever I use a ``wrapfigure``). However, as far as I know, it can work perfectly well depending on the actual content of the list, as it does in this example.